# Limits. Convergence Testing

Tags: limits

If the limit to a function f(x) is 0, does it converge?

In other words, does a function f(x) only diverge if lim f(x) = infinity or -(infinity)?

Many thanks

Comment: Your first sentence is right, the second is wrong. Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a function converges if it has a limit.

If the function does not have a limit, however, you have three options:

1. The limit can, in a general sense, "be" $\infty$
2. The limit can, in a general sense, "be" $-\infty$
3. The limit can, even in a general sense, not exist. An example of this is $f(x)=x\cdot \sin x$, a function for which $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist (it is not even equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Also does an integral from b to a of function f(x) converge if the limit (x->b) f(x) exists?

Comment: @Maths Not necesarily, the integral $\int_0^1 x^{-2} dx$ for example does not exist.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-x$ if $x$ is irrational. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists, but it is not integrable for any interval $[a,b]$